# Sum formula for the first $n$ terms of the form $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+id)(x+iy)^{A+iD}$, where $a,d,A,D,x,y,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I've derived the sum formula for a sequence of the following form:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+id)x^{A+iD}$$

It turns out to be for the first $n$ terms (could probably be expressed in an easier way so bear with me): $$\frac{x^A(-ax^{Dn} + ax^{D(n+1)} - ax^D + a - dnx^{Dn} - dx^{D(n+1)} + dnx^{D(n+1)} + dx^D)}{(x^D - 1)^2}$$

I tried in vain to derive a sum formula for the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+id)(x+iy)^{A+iD} \tag{1}$$

Where $a,d,A,D,x,y,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Does anyone have any ideas where to begin or how to go about finding a sum formula for the $n$ first terms for $(1)$? Even 
managing to get a sum formula that's not exactly of that form would be a step forward.

The context behind this is that it's just my thoughts and ponderings. The answer is most likely rather arduous considering that a sum formula for $(1)$ would in essence be an even further generalization of Faulhaber's formula (sum formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p$, where $p \in \mathbb{N}$).

But I might as well ask to see if someone can come up with any ideas. Thank you.